# Smart casting better then normal casting?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm thinking to switch over to `smart casting` instead of the normal Q and aim thing. But is smart casting really that better then aim and shoot on your command, or will it just slow you down?

Cause i am thinking of switching over now that i'm gonna buy a Razor Naga with 6 buttons on the side for my item activation and use my 6 macro keys for smart casting and summoner spells. and another 4 for leveling up my skills faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart casting is quicker.

Taking Caitlyn's Q for example, it shoots at where my mouse is. I don't aim it.

For targeted spells (say Teemo's Q) it's great for his AA-Q-AA combo out of stealth.

Note that you start the process by holding Q down: you can stop the smart cast by rightclicking if you use smartcast indicators. In this case, you don't commit to it.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence? that if i hold Q down that it keeps triggering?

Comment: He means that smart casts work this way: Hold down ability button to target, then either release it to fire the skill, or press right click while holding the button to cancel the targeting.

Comment: @user1337 As far as i know you can smartcast with ctrl or alt + Q

Comment: It depends on whether the smartcast range indicator is enabled or not. If it's off, the skill is triggered when the key is pressed down. If it's on, the skill is triggered when the key is released and you can cancel it before that.

Comment: @dbemerlin: thanks. I forgot I have indicators "on"

Comment: @Ladineko Smartcasts are made for people to be able to use skills quicker when they have to react fast. Tell me, how do you position your hand when you normally play, and how do you position your hand to use the button combo you mentioned? That's the point of remapping Q,W,E,R to coresponding smartcasts - to not reposition your hand into an awkward position when you have to react faster than usual.

Comment: @user1337 Lets just say the smart cast buttons will be at the left of tab. http://images.bit-tech.net/content_images/2011/03/logitech-510-review/G150-3.jpg G1 to G6 = smartcast, G7-G10 = level up skill and mousewise its my thumb who triggers healthpotions http://rudn2.nodevice.com/static/models_photo/big/040/naga-hex-40701.jpg

Comment: Another great example how smartcasting can be effective is a veigar combo. Where you stun an opponent and you want to use as many of your spells as you can in the little time he's stunned. I've seen people stun a guy and then W -> Deathfire Grasp's Active -> R -> Q. All that in like a second...You can burst almost anyone down from full health mid-late game...